# SQL : Select all field without duplicate data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with field 'code' => '002' duplicate data.

```
---------------------------
| # | code | name | value |
----------------------------
| 1 | 001  |  A   |   2   |
| 2 | 002  |  B   |   4   |
| 3 | 002  |  B   |   6   |
| 4 | 003  |  C   |   3   |
| 5 | 004  |  D   |   1   |
---------------------------
```

All I want to do is to remove duplicate data and choose the higher value. The result is something like this.

```
---------------------------
| # | code | name | value |
----------------------------
| 1 | 001  |  A   |   2   |
| 2 | 002  |  B   |   6   |
| 3 | 003  |  C   |   3   |
| 4 | 004  |  D   |   1   |
---------------------------
```

I've tried query using DISTINCT but only show for single field. I really have no ideas to show all field with no duplicate data.

Please someone help me to figure this out.

thank you so much.

Comment: Is it safe to say that if a record has code `002`, the `name` field will be `B`?

Comment: The column `#` is not fixed? If so, then is it ordered by `code` or row number of the table?

Comment: @finsanurpandi How you are deciding if the record with value 6 has to come not the one with value 2?? How code 003 is having `#` value as 3 instead of 4, it's not stored in the table??Is it just a row number??

Comment: What if code have 2 equal values? then they both are higher values right? in this case which one row do you need to choose ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will give you the exact record (code + name) combination for which the value is maximum

```
Select a.* 
from
your_table_name a
inner join
(
Select code, max(value) as max_val
from your_table_name
group by code
) b
on a.code=b.code and a.value=b.max_val
```

Let me know if you have any questions